# multiple person aproval workflow - how can I tell if everyone approved

Tags: workflow

I have a need for a workflow where multiple people will need to approve something.  They are all on the same level and should get the same task at the same time.  When each person has accepted, I want something to happen.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

After the tasks have been assigned, you will want to do the "each person" tasks in parallel actions (as opposed to serial).  My assumption is that you are using SharePoint Designer 2010.  See if this page helps: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/understand-approval-workflows-in-sharepoint-2010-HA101857172.aspx